# Anjuta and Git tutorial for a beginner?

Tags: git, ide

Is there a beginner-level tutorial on Committing a project created with Anjuta into a Git repository? I could do the initial commit from command line, but I'm really trying to figure out how to do it from within the IDE. I have the Git plugin enabled, but for the life of me can't figure how to move from there. The project for now has just a single source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I manage my repositories with the Terminal, anyway I've found this book quite interesting to learn how to play with git.

http://marketplace.tutsplus.com/item/getting-good-with-git/135967?ref=zreedeecom

and just read another question on this site about the same topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258839/best-git-book-for-a-noob

Answer (score 1):

Git works with folders, once the (.git) folder is present in the folder with the project you want to "git", the git understands this a git folder on your local machine. It can then be synced up with a remote git repository for safe keeping. It may actually be easier to create your remote repository, clone it, then copy your project files into the cloned repository, commit the copied files then push to your remote origin. There is a video about setting it all up here: http://www.ava.co.uk/git